# BARCODE scanner app for IOS

Tags: ios, web-applications, zxing

I was deeply searching for a barcode scanner app that can successfully scan basically all types of barcodes what zxing library can but for ios as external scanner. I am looking for a barcode scanning app that I could invoke from safari and get results back to web page just like we do in android zxing barcodescanner app. I also have tried zbar & pic2shop but pic2shop doesn't scan alphanumeric barcode types such as code128...  zbar app is not really working well. I've installed it and sometimes UI doesnt work.So I am not considering it too, Can someone suggest me an app that could do the job of scanning and has callback url. Thankyou :)

Comment: Hello everyone, Can anyone let me know a barcode scanning app for ios that I can invoke from web page and get the results back to the same window. pic2shop does everything except that it opens a new window :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried native iOS barcode scanning?

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx

Comment: Vitaliy, I would really love to work on a native app and I have idea of how to do that. But using external barcode scanner is what I am trying for(No deployment issues ;))